# How to update Plot and some output inside NDSolve callback (StepMonitor)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following problem.

I am calling NDSolve to solve a system of first order differential equations (nothing fancy), except that the number of equations measures in thousands and the number of terms measures in hundreds of thousands. For such a system I can't even collect InterpolationFunction as it will kill any machine pretty fast. So, I use a callback (StepMonitor) and collect some data there. Apparently I need to know if the solution is "useless" and to determine that I need to look at some graphs and data (which I usually output using Print). Here is an example (sorry for "***Off[Part::pkspec1]***"):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Off[Part::pkspec1];
NoOfElements = 10;
tMax = 100;
plotFrequency = 10;

variables = 
  Table[ToExpression["var" <> ToString[ii]], {ii, 1, 2*NoOfElements}];
initialValues = Table[RandomReal[], {ii, 1, 2*NoOfElements}];
diffEquations = 
  Table[D[variables[[ii]][t], t] == 
    If[Mod[ii, 2] == 1, 
 variables[[ii + 1]][t], -variables[[ii - 1]][t]], {ii, 1, 
2*NoOfElements}];
initialValuesEquations = 
  Table[variables[[ii]][0] == initialValues[[ii]], {ii, 1, 
    2*NoOfElements}];
allEquations = Join[diffEquations, initialValuesEquations];
timeStart = AbsoluteTime[];
callBackCounter = 0;
CallBackResultValues = {};

CallBackFunction[t_?NumericQ, values_?VectorQ] := Module[{result, ii},
   callBackCounter++;
   result = Sum[values[[ii]], {ii, 1, 2*NoOfElements}];
   CallBackResultValues = Join[CallBackResultValues, {{t, result}}];

   If[Mod[callBackCounter, plotFrequency] == 0,
    (
     Print["Total time used = ", (AbsoluteTime[] - timeStart) ];
     Print[
      ParametricPlot[{CallBackResultValues[[Round[ii], 1]], 
        CallBackResultValues[[Round[ii], 2]]}, {ii, 1, 
        callBackCounter}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]];
     )
    ];
   ];

monitor :=
  (
   values = Table[variables[[ii]][t], {ii, 1, 2*NoOfElements}];
   CallBackFunction[t, values];
   );

solution = 
  NDSolve[allEquations, variables, {t, tMax, tMax}, 
   StepMonitor :> monitor];
```

So the question is: how to update the plot (and/or some data) within a callback instead of just printing them and producing tons of unneeded pictures and information.

Thanks a lot.

Konstantin.